# How do I import lokijs in aurelia

Tags: aurelia, lokijs

I recently installed and imported lokijs in aurelia with jspm :

install:

```
jspm  install npm:lokijs
```

import:

```
import * as loki from 'lokijs'
```

the problem is when I want to create a db instance using loki, I get an error saying that 'loki is not a constructor'.

```
var db = new loki('loki.json')
```

> error : > Message: loki is not a constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library actually is not written with ES6 syntax. Simply import it as:

```
import loki from 'lokijs';
```

You can then use it like you have written in your question:

```
var db = new loki('loki.json');
```

Comment: thanks. this is working. for those who need indexedAdaptor can access that by "loki.prototype.getIndexedAdapter()"